# Encoding Eclipse -> Intellij

Tags: eclipse, codificação-de-caracteres, intellij-idea, intellij

Importei um projeto no Intellij que foi criado no eclipse.

O projeto é bem grande.

Estou tendo um problema com o encoding, no eclipse está como Default o `Cp1252`

E o IntelliJ está setado com o `UTF-8`

Como alterar para `Cp1252` ou migrar todo o projeto pra `UTF-8` sem que eu tenha que reescrever tudo?

Se eu setar `UTF-8` no Eclipse

[image: Se eu setar UTF-8 no Eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

Para mudar o encode da criação de arquivos no eclispe, faço os seguintes passos:

Menu Window>Preference. No treeview a esqueda vá em `General>WorkSpace` e mude `text file encoding` para UTF-8.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se eu modificar no eclipse, o código que está no eclipse vai ficar com erro.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago que tipo de erro?

Comment: Já até tentei!!

Comment: Se eu setar de cp1252 pra UTF-8, por exemplo, ele fica dando erro, os caractéres ficam 'loucos'

Comment: coloquei na pergunta @rray

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago se você o encode so desse projeto pelo menu `project>properties` os demais projetos ficam certos incluindo esse migrado?

Comment: Sim, os outros continuam sem erros.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago o comentário resolveu o problema então?

Comment: Não, não resolveu. Continua dando o erro. Acho que vou ter que reescrever.

Comment: olha a String que eu estou passando pelo construtor de Listar..Exception(); tem uns caractéres inválidos

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago se você criar um novo workspace configurado como utf-8 e importar esse projeto para esse workspace continua o problema?

Comment: Sim, continuam os caractéres inválidos

Comment: Isso não resolve. Será necessário salvar todos os arquivos com o encoding correto, pois aparentemente os mesmos foram editados em um que possui caracteres não suportados pelo UTF-8.